# Append HTML document string including tags ASP.NET CodeBehind

Tags: c#, html, webforms

How can I append an html document that includes scripts and tags from c# code behind

I tried appending to a div but that won't work since the script and style tags wont load.

Here's my code so far:

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id= Request.Params["id"] ?? "1";

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>() { "id",id });

        string uri = $"{SERVER_URL}/handlers/httpclient.ashx?method=fetchfile";

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result)
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            HtmlContent.InnerHtml = responseBody;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="HtmlContent" runat="server"></div>
```

The response will return a full html document string like `<!DOCTYPE HTML .. > <html> <head>...scripts & styles</head><body></body>...`

I'm trying to **avoid** saving the document as a temp file and reading from an iframe.

So my main goal is to **append that string while loading the document (server-side)**. Any Help is really appreciated!

Comment: do you want to show the full document with all its inline scripts and inline css? so the iframe one way to get it.

Comment: @Homungus I'm avoiding saving the string as a file on the client's machine. an iframe needs a path to view the document

Comment: No it doesnt need a path, you can either write the content via javacript, so in your case a startup script rendered from code behind, or set the proper iframe content attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the content of an iframe from code behind like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277776/changing-an-iframes-innerhtml-from-codebehind)

e.g.

```
myIframe.Attributes["srcdoc"] = "responseBody";
```

or you create a startup script which inserts the content in the iframe.